# Captured Video on iPhone, trying to move it to another directory

Tags: iphone, ios4

Using `UIImagePickerController`, I have captured a video.  When I call `[picker stopVideoCapture]`,  then the following delegate method is called:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"attempting to copy: %@ to: %@", [url absoluteString], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rawMovie.MOV",path]);


if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:[url absoluteString] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rawMovie.MOV",path] error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Can't move file with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

When this method is called however, it returns an error reading:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
```

As far as I have been able to tell, this means that the file cannot be copied for some unknown reason.  Can anyone give me a better answer as to why this error is being thrown?  Or, better yet, can anyone tell me the best way to save the captured video directly to the app's documents directory?

Thanks, 
James

Comment: After all I just ended up using AVFoundation instead of UIImagePickerController.  That way I was able to save directly to the documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you put breakpoints & see the output of `*path` and `url`. Also do you have enough disk space to store your video on the device?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the default file manager:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

You can also log the error's userinfo for (hopefully) more details.

```
NSLog(@"Can't move file with error: %@", [error userInfo]);
```